# Float a div within a div on scroll down and up (not on whole screen)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have made a div witin div, i want the inner div to float up and down on scrolling page up and down within the outer div. I have somehow managed to make it restrict not to go out of the outer div form to but when it comes to bottom it goes down till bottom of the page. please help me, here is my code
css

**CSS**

```
#comment {
  position: absolute;
  /* just used to show how to include the margin in the effect */
}
```

**HTML**

```
<!--the outer div in which i have whole content -->
<div class="content">
    <!--the floating div, remains well inside form top but moves down outside div from bottom -->
    <div class="ftwrapper" id="comment">            
    </div><!--fb/twitter ends-->
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
    $(function () {
        var msie6 = $.browser == 'msie' && $.browser.version < 7;
        if (!msie6) {
            var top = $('#comment').offset().top - parseFloat($('#comment').css('margin-top').replace(/auto/, 0));
            $(window).scroll(function (event) {
                // what the y position of the scroll is
                var y = $(this).scrollTop();

                // whether that's below the form
                if (y >= top) {
                    // if so, ad the fixed class
                    $('#comment').addClass('fixed');
                } else {
                    // otherwise remove it
                    $('#comment').removeClass('fixed');
                }
            });
        }  
    });
```

Comment: It sounds like you want something like [StickyFloat](http://dropthebit.com/demos/stickyfloat/stickyfloat.html)?

Comment: see www.webabinc.com/test , you will see a div on right side, that float down well, but the problem is i want to restrict it within the outer div, the content div, but as i add footer at bottom, it comes over that footer as well

Comment: You basically need to keep it within the container, and not go over the footer, etc?

Comment: Looks like facebooks sidebar has the behavior you are looking for. 
perhaps you can search their source code and see how it works .

Comment: i just nee t to be in the container, any solutions please, need to do it fast

Comment: i need code of something like this
http://dropthebit.com/demos/stickyfloat/stickyfloat.html

Answer (score 1):

I made a sample test based on your requirement.
It doesnt work well if scrolled too fast, but otherwise its ok. Ill make some changes to it later.

```
var prevScroll = 0;
$(window).unbind("scroll");
function reposition() {
    var contPos  = $("#container").offset();
    var comment = $('#comment');    
    contPos.bottom = contPos.top + $("#container").outerHeight();
    console.log('contPos',contPos);
    $(window).scroll(function (event) {
        // what the y position of the scroll is
        var     scroll = $(window).scrollTop()
            ,   y = scroll
            ,   pos = comment.offset()
        ;
        pos.bottom = comment.outerHeight();
        if ( scroll > prevScroll) {
            //down
        } else {
            //up
        }
        prevScroll = scroll;
        // whether that's below the form
        console.log(pos.bottom + scroll ,":", contPos.bottom);
        if (contPos.top > scroll) {
            // if so, ad the fixed class
            comment.css({
                position: 'relative',
                bottom  : '0px',
                left    : '0px'
            });
            console.log("Too High");
        } else if ( pos.bottom + scroll > contPos.bottom) {
            //comment.removeClass('fixed');
            comment.css({
                position: 'absolute',
                top      : (contPos.bottom - comment.outerHeight() )+'px',
                left     : pos.left+'px'
            });

            console.log("Too Low");
        } else {
            // middle area
            console.log("Perfect");
            comment.css({
                position: 'fixed',
                top   : '0px',
                left  : pos.left + 'px'
            });
        }
    });
}
$(document).ready(reposition);
```

[Jsfiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/rainerpl/rnt6c/10/)